# Deploy simple HTTP Maven (jax-rs) server jar on heroku

Tags: maven, heroku, server, jar, jax-rs

i'm having some troubles trying to deploy a VERY basic server on heroku, all that i need the server for is some testing on an android app i'm developing.

Here is the Server.java code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    JAXRSServerFactoryBean factoryBean = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setResourceClasses(PipBoyRepository.class);
    PipBoyRepository wr = new PipBoyRepository();
    wr.setConnection();

    factoryBean.setResourceProvider(new SingletonResourceProvider(wr));

    factoryBean.setAddress("https://pipboy2022.herokuapp.com:8080/");

    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
    providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
    factoryBean.setProviders(providers);

    BindingFactoryManager manager = 
      factoryBean.getBus().getExtension(BindingFactoryManager.class);
    
    JAXRSBindingFactory restFactory = new JAXRSBindingFactory();
    restFactory.setBus(factoryBean.getBus());
    
    manager.registerBindingFactory(JAXRSBindingFactory.JAXRS_BINDING_ID,
                                     restFactory);
    
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server server = factoryBean.create();

    System.out.println("Server ready...");

    while (true) {
    }
}
```

Here is my POM.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.sapienza.softeng</groupId>
    <artifactId>pipboy-webserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.28.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> 
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId> 
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.1</version>
          </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>it.sapienza.softeng.api.withjson.and.dbms.Server</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Optional Start -->
                            <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                            <!-- Optional End -->
    
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>it.sapienza.softeng.api.withjson.and.dbms.Server</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-xml.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt</resource>
                                </transformer>
    
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http-jetty.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml</resource>
                                </transformer>
    
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <appName>pipboy2022</appName>
            <includeTarget>false</includeTarget>
            <includes>
            <include>target/pipboy-webserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar</include>
            </includes>
            <processTypes>
                <web>java -jar target/pipboy-webserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar</web>
            </processTypes>

        </configuration>        
      </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When i try to deploy using:

```
mvn clean heroku:deploy
```

i get this error:

```
2022-01-25T14:21:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-25T14:21:12.231638+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2022-01-25T14:21:12.234638+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765460+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765542+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:216)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765568+00:00 app[web.1]: at it.sapienza.softeng.api.withjson.and.dbms.Server.main(Server.java:44)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765628+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Protocol mismatch for port 8080: engine's protocol is http, the url protocol is https
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765653+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.finalizeConfig(JettyHTTPDestination.java:168)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765678+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(HTTPTransportFactory.java:288)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765702+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:85)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765726+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:64)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765750+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:170)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765774+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 1 more
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765815+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Protocol mismatch for port 8080: engine's protocol is http, the url protocol is https
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765854+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.createJettyHTTPServerEngine(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.java:277)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765879+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.createJettyHTTPServerEngine(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.java:307)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765913+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.retrieveEngine(JettyHTTPDestination.java:134)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765926+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.finalizeConfig(JettyHTTPDestination.java:166)
2022-01-25T14:21:12.765946+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 5 more
2022-01-25T14:21:12.866903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-25T14:21:12.921103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-25T14:21:12.938923+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-25T14:21:15.612557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar target/pipboy-webserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
2022-01-25T14:21:16.699261+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2022-01-25T14:21:16.702666+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489264+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489367+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:216)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489393+00:00 app[web.1]: at it.sapienza.softeng.api.withjson.and.dbms.Server.main(Server.java:44)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489458+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Protocol mismatch for port 8080: engine's protocol is http, the url protocol is https
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489484+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.finalizeConfig(JettyHTTPDestination.java:168)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489508+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(HTTPTransportFactory.java:288)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489535+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:85)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489559+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:64)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489583+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:170)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489611+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 1 more
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489655+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Protocol mismatch for port 8080: engine's protocol is http, the url protocol is https
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489704+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.createJettyHTTPServerEngine(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.java:277)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489730+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.createJettyHTTPServerEngine(JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.java:307)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489757+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.retrieveEngine(JettyHTTPDestination.java:134)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489782+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.finalizeConfig(JettyHTTPDestination.java:166)
2022-01-25T14:21:17.489804+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 5 more
2022-01-25T14:21:17.608228+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-25T14:21:17.660646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-25T14:21:51.884018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pipboy2022.herokuapp.com request_id=ce41a171-a7e0-45dd-94dd-fa4a759c2616 fwd="79.45.1.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-25T14:21:52.006333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pipboy2022.herokuapp.com request_id=f32fe23f-74b3-43a3-84c2-0be324164589 fwd="79.45.1.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-25T14:21:58.047298+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/weapons" host=pipboy2022.herokuapp.com request_id=a3899f90-4d60-4351-ad79-31caac2e7505 fwd="79.45.1.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-25T14:21:58.102843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/weapons" host=pipboy2022.herokuapp.com request_id=90b37f28-5467-4ed7-ab21-e44d4fb7020e fwd="79.45.1.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-25T14:21:58.385152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pipboy2022.herokuapp.com request_id=f9742e2d-7f5d-4f59-a310-4278422e5859 fwd="79.45.1.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

after searching this issue online i found out many people reporting issues with cxf versions, but i tried those fixes with no result.

### Edit:

After trying the Fix suggested by @Chris the error changed and now when i try to deploy i get this:

```
2022-01-25T19:08:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-25T19:08:41.505337+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar target/pipboy-webserver-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
2022-01-25T19:08:42.417781+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2022-01-25T19:08:42.421138+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2022-01-25T19:08:42.679385+00:00 app[web.1]: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils).
2022-01-25T19:08:42.679788+00:00 app[web.1]: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
2022-01-25T19:08:42.679789+00:00 app[web.1]: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2022-01-25T19:08:43.338711+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
2022-01-25T19:08:43.338823+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:216)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.338858+00:00 app[web.1]: at it.sapienza.softeng.api.withjson.and.dbms.Server.main(Server.java:44)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339000+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not start Jetty server on port 36,202: Failed to bind to pipboy2022.herokuapp.com/54.220.192.176:36202
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339000+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:485)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339002+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:187)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339036+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:53)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339077+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBindingFactory.java:95)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339110+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSBindingFactory.addListener(JAXRSBindingFactory.java:91)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339141+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:128)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339173+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:209)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339209+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 1 more
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339291+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to pipboy2022.herokuapp.com/54.220.192.176:36202
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339324+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339355+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339387+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339418+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339466+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339499+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339530+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339563+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:474)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339590+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 7 more
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339671+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339707+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339739+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339772+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339802+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339832+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339866+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
2022-01-25T19:08:43.339894+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 14 more
2022-01-25T19:08:43.481104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-25T19:08:43.772520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
factoryBean.setAddress("https://pipboy2022.herokuapp.com:8080/");
```

You don't get to pick your port on Heroku.

[Your app will be assigned a port dynamically every time it starts via the `PORT` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers). I'm far from a Java expert, but I believe you can do something like this:

```java
factoryBean.setAddress("https://pipboy2022.herokuapp.com:" + System.getenv("PORT"));
```

Note that this is just the port your app should *listen on*. To connect to it from a browser or from your Android app, simply omit the port. Heroku will route requests from the standard HTTPS and HTTP ports to your app.

Comment: Thanks  for the answer, but it didn't completely solve the problem, now when i deploy i get the error `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not start Jetty server on port 36,202: Failed to bind to pipboy2022.herokuapp.com/54.220.192.176:36202`

Comment: Hrm. Looks like it's trying to use a domain _and_ an IP address for some reason... I'm not familiar with this library but will see what I can dig up.

Comment: @PaoloAccaputo, are you literally doing `factoryBean.setAddress("https://pipboy2022.herokuapp.com:" + System.getenv("PORT"));` as I show here? Because `"https://pipboy2022.herokuapp.com:"` is a literal string, and since the IP address comes _before_ the `:` in the error you show I'm not clear on how it could get in there.

Comment: Looks like for some reason inside PORT there are both the IP and the port, so i tried to set as address just `Syste.getenv("PORT")`, now there are no errors but the app doesnt load and after 90ish seconds it says "app boot timeout"

Comment: The `PORT` environment variable should only contain the port. Do you do anything else with it in your application? Are you trying to modify it somehow?